# How can I use an array of words and an array of child nodes to recreate a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to wrap each individual word in `<span></span>` while keeping all of the other nodes (link, bold, etc). I have successfully taken all of the words on each page and put them in an array, and have taken all of the child nodes and put them in an array as well. Is there any way to put this paragraph back together, with everything in the right place (certain words inside certain tags), by using these two arrays?

Heres my code:

```
 p.each(function () {
    var current = $(this);

    var children = current.children().toArray();

    var text = current.text();

    var textNodes = text.split(' ');

    for (var i = 0; i < textNodes.length; i++) {
        this.childNodes[i].replaceChild(textNodes, this.childNodes[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and show a [mcve] with expected output

Comment: Also why mix jQuery and DOM

Comment: [Why are you trying to do this?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: I'm using .offsetTop to find the height of words in a paragraph so I can identify each line in the paragraph. I need to wrap the words in span tags because text inside the paragraph element doesn't have the DOM property of .offsetTop, but the span tags do. I also need a way to preserve all of the other nodes within the paragraph, so the text is the same, with additional span tags around the words. @1252748

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using native JavaScript, this should function does what you are wanting. 
I am not familiar with jQuery, but this should be compatible since it is just JS. Also, this is a lot faster than setting innerHTML.

```js
const walkChildrenAndWrapWordsInSpans = node => {
  if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    const { parentElement } = node
    node.textContent
      .trim()
      .split(' ')
      .forEach(word => {
        let span = document.createElement("span");
        span.innerText = ' ' + word;
        parentElement.insertBefore(span, node);
      });
    parentElement.removeChild(node);
  }
  if (node.childNodes) {
    [...node.childNodes].forEach(walkChildrenAndWrapWordsInSpans);
  }
};

[...document.querySelectorAll('p')].forEach(walkChildrenAndWrapWordsInSpans)
```

Comment: Hmm, in this fiddle it jumbles the words: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/zqsaphuc/

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan. I updated it with the fix for what you were seeing. Though I admit there is an extra break line added to the DOM that I can't figure out where it is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

This one ALMOST works. It does however replace the url in the href too but perhaps that is not an issue for your specific text

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/k3o9t18g/

```js
$('p').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.text()
    .split(/\s+/)
    .forEach(word => {
        console.log(word);
      $this.html($this.html().replace(word,`<span>${word}</span>`))
    });
});
```

```css
span {
  outline: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <strong>Lorem ipsum</strong> <i>sit amet</i> 
  <a href="#test">Curabitur vel bibendum leo</a> Duis eros nunc, aliquam
</p>

<p>The <b>quick</b> brown <a href="fox">fox</a> jumps 
over<br/> the <i>lazy dog</i></p>
```

Comment: Fixed it with \s